# Locate owner of a computer on file system

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

I am trying to locate the owners name from a computer that was turned in, in order to return it.  I am unfamiliar with Linux, and would prefer if I could be directed to a location in the actual file system, rather than a command so I can avoid powering it on, as I can access the drive via write blocker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/passwd` is the list of users for the system, and has an optional field for full name. Even if their real name isn't included, you might be able to figure something out from the username. '1000' is a common user id value, so look for lines like

```
jason:x:1000:1000:Jason Lastname,,,:/home/jason:/bin/bash
```

---

If you want to go beyond system-level files and start snooping through their documents, the user's home directory would be in `/home/username/`. From there, common directories like `Desktop` and `Documents` would hold files that, like on any other PC, would be visible in the Desktop view or quickly available from the Documents menus in applications. For example, if it's a student, you might find folders in Documents/ sorted by class names or semesters, and opening one might find the student's name.

---

Nice suggestion by @Anony-Mousse: if this computer was mostly used as a shell to connect to other computers, you could check their command-line history for clues like login names on servers you might be able to comapre against. The command-line history is usually stored in the home directory in a file named like `.history` or `.bash_history`.

Comment: Looks like they didn't fill in a last name.  I located that line in the passwd, and it has just - Mia,,,: etc.  Just a first name to go on at this moment.  Slightly more than I had when starting though, so that is a positive.

Comment: No such luck in there either, i also tried looking into the .mozilla to see if there might be something in config for it.  There were no documents with names. It looked as though the machine was not heavily used, even the .mozilla was relatively empty.

Comment: Try the `.history` file in the users home directory. It may contain a call like `ssh mlastname@lab.university.edu` that you may be able to map to an email address.

Comment: Excellent idea but it does look like I'm running out of options.  There is a lack of any .history or .bash_history file at all.  It's also a custom machine with no S/N on it for me to contact a manufacturer.  With no last name filled in, no internet history, no personal documents, and now seemingly no command line history, we may be at a dead end.